# Characterization of discrete random variables in terms of their (cumulative) distribution function

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables

It is well-known that the cdf (just 'distribution function' from now on) of a discrete random variable is a "staircase function" going from 0 at minus infinity to 1 at plus infinity. Intuitively this is quite clear. I would like to make the notion of 'staircase function' precise, and also to show a "characterization theorem", namely one of the form:

**Theorem.** Let $X$ be a random variable. Then $X$ is discrete if and only if the distribution function $F_X$ of $X$ satisfies (...).

To further explain I will first recall the basic definitions used here:

**Definition.** Let $X$  be a
random variable.
We say that $X$ is *finitely discrete*
if and only if
there exists
a finite set $C \subseteq \mathbb R$
such that
$P( X \in C ) = 1$.
More generally we say that $X$ is
*discrete*
if and only if
there exists
a countable set $C \subseteq \mathbb R$
such that
$P( X \in C ) = 1$.

For the case when $X$ is what I call 'finitely discrete' (i.e., it can essentially only take on a finite number of values), I think (but I'm not sure) the following holds:

**Theorem 1.** Let $X$ be a random variable. Then $X$ is finitely discrete if and only if the distribution function $F_X$ of $X$ satisfies

1. $\mbox{range} (F_X)$ is finite;
2. $F_X$ is non-decreasing;
3. $F_X$ is right-continuous at each point;
4. $\lim_{x\to -\infty}  F_X = 0$ and  $\lim_{x\to +\infty} F_X = 1$.

*Question.* Can someone confirm if this indeed holds?

Now to deal with the more general case, I would like to show the following:

**Theorem 2.** Let $X$ be a random variable. Then $X$ is discrete if and only if the distribution function $F_X$ of $X$ satisfies

1. $\mbox{range} (F_X)$ is countable;
2. $F_X$ is non-decreasing;
3. $F_X$ is right-continuous at each point;
4. $\lim_{x\to -\infty}  F_X = 0$ and  $\lim_{x\to +\infty} F_X = 1$.

*Question.*  Is the statement from Theorem 2 true? Alas I have not been able to give a proof. If someone could give a hint, or perhaps refer to some literature that details these matters futher, that would be great.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Range of $F_X$ need not be countable.